# Combinatorics: Number of Integer Solutions for $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 < 56$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Number of integer solutions for  $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 < 56$ where:

a) $x_i \geq  0$, for $1 \leq i \leq 6$

b) $x_i \geq  -2$, for $1 \leq i \leq 6$

For part (a) the answer I got is $C(60,6) = 50,063,860$. Is this correct? I'm not sure how to do (b).

Comment: For (b), define $y_i=x_i+2$, then substitute. Note that $y_i \geq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, for Part (a), let $$x_7:=55-x_1-x_2-x_3-x_4-x_5-x_6\,.$$  Therefore, we are to solve for $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_7)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^7$ from the equation
$$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_7=55\,.$$
There are, by the star-and-bar method,
$$\binom{55+7-1}{7-1}=55525372$$
solutions, as confirmed by Anurag A.

For Part (b), with the substitution $y_i:=x_i+2$ and $$y_7:=67-y_1-y_2-y_3-y_4-y_5-y_6\,,$$
we are to solve for $\left(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_7\right)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^7$ from the equation
$$y_1+y_2+\ldots+y_7=67\,.$$
As before, there are
$$\binom{67+7-1}{7-1}=170230452$$
solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For (a). solutions to the inequality $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 < 56$ are the union of the solution set of ALL of the following equations.
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = k \quad \text{ where } k \in \{0,1,2, \ldots ,55\}.$$
For a given $k$, the number of solutions are given by
$$\binom{k+6-1}{6-1}=\binom{k+5}{5}.$$
So the total number of solutions for the inequality will be
$$\sum_{k=0}^{55}\binom{k+5}{5}=\color{blue}{55525372}.$$

For (b), define $y_i=x_i+2$, then substitute. Note that $y_i \geq 0$. Now use the method of (a).